# CUDA Efficient nd-array(tensor) slicing

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda

Let's say I have 3d array as flatten 1d with sizes `[N, M, K]`. And I want to process a slice from it like `[0:N, 1:M, 0:K]`.
I've created a helper function that addresses underlying array by indexes from sliced array(for simplicity I only slice by second dimension).

```
#define N somevalue
#define M somevalue
#define K somevalue
// i is an index in sliced array so we need to translate it into original one
template<class T, int FROM>
 __device__   __forceinline__ T slice(const T * const __restrict__ x, const size_t i) {
    auto batch_size = (M - FROM) * K;
    auto batch_index = i / batch_size;
    auto offset_0 = i % batch_size;
    auto offset_1 = offset_0 / STATES;
    auto offset_2 = offset_0 % STATES;

    return x[batch_index * M * K + (offset_1 + FROM) * K + offset_2];
}
```

From NVidia profiler I see that division and modulo division take a lot of computational power. Also sizes is not a power of 2, so I can't use shift bits trick directly.

What can you advise?
As I know slicing is a quite common operation in TF, so how do they solved it?

Comment: Do you need to always use random access, or can you use foreach type of constructs in many cases?

Comment: Don't fully understand your question. A computational kernel uses the function to process the whole slice `[0:N, 1:M, 0:K]`

Comment: Does a kernel absolutely have to be of the form: `for(int i=0;i<...;++i) f(slice(x,i))`? I don't have experience with cuda...

Comment: I works a little bit differently in cuda, but yes. All range must be processed.

Answer (score 1):

Cuda is about coalesced memory access and simd. And *arbitrary* slices are the exact opposite. So the answer as usual: it depends.

If your offset is and remains 1, change you memory layout towards M N K. If the ignored entries are really really sparse, go with the traditional way and just idle a few threads (yes this hurts, but some threadIdx calc without modulo might be faster). Otherwise, you will need to compute this bijective mapping thread/block-id to element-id like you wrote in your question.

There are some ways to represent modulo by some other operations. But it's commonly better to invest time in improving other parts of the kernel.